# I have 32 gig of ram and blender 2.8 becomes sluggish and jittery and becomes unresponsive when I load a scene with 3,332 objects and 1.4M triangles?

Tags: objects, gpu, performance, memory-management

I have 32 gig of ram and blender becomes sluggish and jittery and becomes unresponsive when I load a scene with 3,332 objects and 1.4 triangles ?

I forgot to mention there are over 900 armatures in the scene.

My computer: HP Pavilion 690
AMD Proc Ryzen 3, 2200G
Radeon Vega Graphics 3.5 GHZ
Ram 32GB

Also when checking the processes there appears to be a memory leak associated with Blender. Once I close and reload the memory is released.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: If you have 900 armatures and 1.4M tris, I suspect you're probably trying to do a lot more armature deformation than you can get away with.  I believe CPU (probably single threaded) is limiting factor for armature deformation.  While a memory leak isn't unlikely, you should also consider the memory used by your undo buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it has confirmed my suspicions. Can you tell me roughly how many objects, triangles, armatures, blender 2.8 can function within a single scene, without loosing performance?

Comment: No, because 1) the answer is 0, you start to lose performance the instant you do anything and 2) it depends on what you do, there are a thousand things that can be going on a file and they act differently from each other.